# Why is this not considered as a default constructor?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm confused between the default constructor.
I've 2 codes, code A and code B

In code A I don't understand why `A(int news)` is not considered as default constructor whereas code B `ParentClass(int id)` is consider as default constructor

Why does code A isn't able to compile but code B is able to compile.

code A

```
    class A{
public:
    int s;
       A(int news){
 s = news;
}
    void print()
    {
    cout << s;
    }
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    a.print();

}
```

code B

```
    class ParentClass{
public:
    int id;
    ParentClass(int id){
    this->id = id;
    }

    void print(){
        cout << id <<endl;
    }
};

class ChildClass:public ParentClass
{
public:
    int id;
    ChildClass(int id):ParentClass(1)
    {
        this->id = id;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ChildClass c(2);
    c.print();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the edit, question finally becomes clear. Rewording my answer.

Preface. In C++, a default constructor is a constructor which has no arguments, or has default values for all it's arguments. It is used to create an object when no additional information is provided. For example,

```
Default a;
Default* p = new A;
```

In the code above, default constructor of `Default` is called.

In the example `A` you are trying to call default constructor of `A` - because `A a` calls A's default constructor. Since such constructor doesn't exist, you have a compilation error. The only constructor you've got is a one taking integer argument, and you can use following code to call it:

```
A a(42);
```

In the second example, you are calling **non**-default (user-provided) constructor of `ChildClass` - becasue `ChildClass c(1)` calls a constructor of `ChildClass` accepting one integer argument - and you have just that. By the way, this `ChildClass` constructor calls `ParentClass` constructor, which takes exactly one integer argument.

Comment: so code A have a non-default constructor right? Why when I run it, it will says that there's no default constructor? Whereas for code B it will run.

Comment: I mean, if I run code A, it will give an error, saying default constructor is not defined. But when I run code B it run successfully.. Another question, is it a MUST to have default constructor?

Comment: No, it is not a must, but arguments must be supplied whenever the object is created if it lacks a default constructor

Comment: @overflow, you need to provide the full code you are compiling. In the **question** itself.

Comment: I'm very confused, why some code without default constructor can run while some can't

Comment: @overflowhow, **some** code is different from **another** code. Show us the code, and we will tell you exactly.

Comment: updated full source code.. Why code B without default constructor can run but code A doesn't

Comment: In the posted code, A has a default constructor, while `ParentClass` does not. What's the question, again?

Comment: Both doesn't have default constructor, both using non-default constructor. Why code A have an error stating that there's no default constructor when I'm compiling whereas code B able to compile successfully

Comment: @overflowhow, this is just wrong. `A` does have default constructor. Your code compiles just fine if one is to include `iostream`, proper use `cout` and remove extra `;`.

Comment: @SergeyA the previous code is after resolving the error.

Comment: @overflowhow, edited my answer to answer the question, since finally it is clear what are you asking about.

Comment: Thanks~(: @SergeyA